# Collision detection problem in Java

Tags: java, game-mechanics, platformer, eclipse

I have a problem in my game. My player cannot move after I put collision detection from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DadImcUt9Nk&index=22&list=PLah6faXAgguMnTBs3JnEJY0shAc18XYQZ

And I made my Mario like game using these videos. I followed all the things said in the video and the whole series from episode 1 to 22. before implementing the code from episode 22, my game worked fine. But after implementing the code for collision detection, my player stopped moving. And I checked through the code and I didn't find any error. I hope you guys can help me on this as I'm new to coding.

Thanks :D

My code

(**EntityClass**)

```
  protected Handler handler;
  protected float x, y;
  protected int width, height;
  protected Rectangle bounds;

  public Entity(Handler handler, float x, float y, int width, int height){
    this.handler = handler;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  public abstract void tick();

  public abstract void render(Graphics g);

  public float getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public float getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public int getHeight() {
    return height;
  }

  public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
  }
}
```

(**WorldClass**)

```
  private Handler handler;
  private int width, height;
  private int spawnX, spawnY;
  private int[][] tiles;

  public World(Handler handler, String path){
    this.handler = handler;
    loadWorld(path);
  }

  public void tick(){

  }

  public void render(Graphics g){
    int xStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamer().getxOffset() / Tile.TILEWIDTH);
    int xEnd = (int) Math.min(width, (handler.getGameCamer().getxOffset() + handler.getWidth()) / Tile.TILEWIDTH + 1);
    int yStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamer().getyOffset() / Tile.TILEHEIGHT);
    int yEnd = (int) Math.min(height, (handler.getGameCamer().getyOffset() + handler.getHeight()) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT +1);

    for(int y = yStart;y < yEnd;y++){
      for(int x = xStart;x < xEnd;x++){
        getTile(x, y).render(g, (int) (x * Tile.TILEWIDTH - handler.getGameCamer().getxOffset()),
            (int) (y * Tile.TILEHEIGHT - handler.getGameCamer().getyOffset()));
      }
    }
  }

  public Tile getTile(int x, int y){
    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height)
      return Tile.grassTile;

    Tile t = Tile.tiles[tiles[x][y]];
    if(t == null)
      return Tile.grassTile;
    return t;
  }

  private void loadWorld(String path){
    String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
    String[] tokens = file.split("\\s+");
    width = Utils.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    height = Utils.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    spawnX = Utils.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    spawnY = Utils.parseInt(tokens[3]);

    tiles = new int[width][height];
    for(int y = - 0;y < height;y++){
      for(int x = 0;x < width;x++){
        tiles[x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[(x + y * width) + 4]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(**CreaturesClass**)

```
  public static final int DEFAULT_HEALTH = 1;
  public static final float DEFAULT_SPEED = 3.0f;
  public static final int DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH = 128,
                          DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT = 128;

  protected int health;
  protected float speed;
  protected float xMove, yMove;

  public Creatures(Handler handler, float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    super(handler, x, y, width, height);
    health = DEFAULT_HEALTH;
    speed = DEFAULT_SPEED; 
    xMove = 0;
    yMove = 0;
  }

  public void move(){
    moveX();
    moveY();
  }

  public void moveX(){
    if(xMove > 0){//Moving right
      int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

      if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT) &&
          !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)){
        x += xMove;
      }
    }else if(xMove < 0){//Moving left
  int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

      if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT) &&
          !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)){
        x +=xMove;
      }
    }
  }

  public void moveY(){
    if(yMove < 0){//Up
      int ty = (int) (y + yMove + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT;

      if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty) &&
          !collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty)){
        y += yMove;
      }
    }else if(yMove > 0){//Down
      int ty = (int) (y + yMove + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT;

      if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty) &&
          !collisionWithTile((int) (x + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH, ty)){
        y += yMove;
      }
    }
  }

  protected boolean collisionWithTile(int x, int y){
    return handler.getWorld().getTile(x, y).isSolid();
  }

  //GETTERS AND SETTERS

  public float getxMove() {
    return xMove;
  }

  public void setxMove(float xMove) {
    this.xMove = xMove;
  }

  public float getyMove() {
    return yMove;
  }

  public void setyMove(float yMove) {
    this.yMove = yMove;
  }

  public int getHealth() {
    return health;
  }

  public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
  }

  public float getSpeed() {
    return speed;
  }

  public void setSpeed(float speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
  }
}
```

(**PlayerClass**)

```
  public Player(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
    super(handler, x, y, Creatures.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH, Creatures.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT);

    bounds.x = 32;
    bounds.y = 32;
    bounds.width = 92;
    bounds.height = 96;
  }

  @Override
  public void tick() {
    getInput();
    move();
    handler.getGameCamer().centerOnEntity(this);
  }

  private void getInput(){
    xMove = 0;
    yMove = 0;

    if(handler.getKeyManager().up)
      yMove = -speed;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().down)
      yMove = speed;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().left)
      xMove = -speed;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().right)
      xMove = speed;
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(Assets.DerpDino, (int) (x - handler.getGameCamer().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getGameCamer().getyOffset()), width, height, null);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect((int) (x + bounds.x - handler.getGameCamer().getxOffset()),
            (int) (y + bounds.y - handler.getGameCamer().getyOffset()),
            bounds.width, bounds.height);
  }
}
```

Comment: Guys I fixed the problem. I read through all of my code and I found out is my Tile Class, I set the 'isSolid' method to true. so all the tiles are solid.

Comment: Protip: Don't start with a game if you're new to programming.

Comment: Now im not that new and i fixed this issue

Comment: im implementing gravity and jumping now